# Adding a single checkboxinput

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I'm looking for a way to add a checkboxInput, it should display the waiting times and interruptions for this dataset when ticked.
I'm  a complete newbie to rstudio and have no idea what I'm doing. 
The code for the program is:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

library(tidyverse)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Choice A", value = TRUE),
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So far after running the code and trying to fix it I just get the same error.
Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you currently pass three arguments to the function `sidebarLayout`, altough only two arguments are expected. The ui definition in the question looks as follows

```
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(...)
    ),
    checkboxInput(...),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(...)
    )
  )
)
```

(I used `...` as placeholders to make the code more readable.) The `checkboxInput` should go in either of the panels. For example

```
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(...),
      checkboxInput(...)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(...)
    )
  )
)
```